# File Download in anroid java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream

Tags: android

```
private String downloadFile(String MY_URL) {
        int count;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(MY_URL);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            int lengthOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
            fileName = MY_URL.substring(MY_URL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, MY_URL.length());
            File outputFile = new File(directory, fileName);
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;

                int status = (int) ((total * 100) / lengthOfFile);
                output.write(data, 0, count);

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Connectivity Manager

                        //speedTV.setText(downSpeed+" mbps");
                        // speedTV.setText(finalRate);
                        progress_circular_id.setProgress(status);
                        textview_progress_status_id.setText(String.valueOf(status) + "%");

                        if (status == 100) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });


            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
            return "Downloaded at: " + directory.getPath() + fileName;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Abhan", "Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    hideProgressDialog();

                }
            });
        }
        hideProgressDialog();
        return "Downloading Error";
    }
```

this is my code i am trying to download image and save in to phone storage trying to show progress status  in textview_progress_status_id .

its starting download  but its take too much  time its not downloading its returning exception
java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream

please help me what is root cause or i am doing some mistake .

Comment: Post the stacktrace from the LogCat please. And finish your other question.

Comment: For a test just download the file without using progress indicaters and textviews and so. Please post your cleaned up code too here. Just post relevant code... well .. see if it differs..

Comment: thanks for answer i want to download this image url in our phone with progress https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.png please help me with this i  have tried  this example

Comment: I would recommend to also used a BufferedOutputStream with a buffer of about 32K, otherwise there will be many redundant write operations to flash memory. The BufferedInputStream is in my opinion not very helpful, you should be able to omit it without consequences. The other code parst looks good, so if the download is not finished correctly this may be caused by the server not the client code. BTW: I would not class `dialog.dismiss();` while the receive loop is running (because then download is still running). Move that in a new handler.post block right after the loop has finished.